# TS function variable args type issue

Tags: typescript

I have this interface declared:

```
interface XhrCaller {
    (...args: (string|unknown)[]): Promise<Record<string, unknown>>
}
```

When I go ahead to define a `get` fn like

`const getCall : XhrCaller = (pathParam: string) => new Promise((resolve, reject) ...`

I get an error that says

> Type '(pathParam: string) => Promise<Record<string, unknown>' is not assignable to type 'XhrCaller'

Clearly, there is an issue with the way I have declared the interface.

Please help.

Comment: What is the intent of `XhrCaller`?  Why annotate `aFunction` with anything?  Your `aFunction` can only accept a `string` but `XhrCaller` needs to be able to accept any number of any type of parameters.  Those aren't compatible.  But I'm not sure whether to tell you to change `aFunction`, change `XhrCaller`, or change something else.

Comment: Its the unknown type which can not be assigned to the string type which breaks your code. It works with any. Read more on: https://mariusschulz.com/blog/the-unknown-type-in-typescript

Comment: @jcalz  The interface is going to be used for multiple functions which all have a similar type and hence this generic interface. Let me update my question to make more sense of what I'm saying.

Comment: @thecOdemOnkey but I am creating a union. Doesn't that work?

Comment: Can you make a [mcve] of some code that uses multiple functions for some purpose? Presumably the only reason you care about using `XhrCaller` at all is that something is going to be accepting values of type `XhrCaller` and calling them.  Let's see some of those, and I can advise.  In order for functions to be called safely they need to be contravariant in their argument types (see [`--strictFunctionTypes` docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html#strict-function-types)) so you need to be careful.

Comment: @AakashVerma if you define getCall as a XhrCaller it needs to match the definition so it must be string|unknown. What do you want to achive? If you want to have only string parameters then you could use "never" instead of unknown. If you want strings or anything else then it would be the same as any.

Comment: @thecOdemOnkey I can have a `postCall` method too which apart from `pathParam` as string can take say an object called `body`. Do you get it now?

Comment: @AakashVerma okay that gets well past that first question so a more detailed description  would help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have already declare type for `XhrCaller`, you don't have to annotate `pathParam` TypeScript already know its type is `string|unknown`

Link to [TS Playground:](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgBoAsoGE4BtfTIDeAsAFDKXIAUAdPXFAOYDOAXDS2FKE8gD7IAriADWIAPYB3EAEoA2gF1ZHAApQJAW2AsIAHgBKEBBKgATPVx4gmAGmFjJMgHzPyAX3LkTILsiYQYDj4yBwY2HgEUMgAvDQADnBg6KqMcJqysc7IIBBSyOpaOhDU1FAQLBK4AG4Q9uUAVsZgmTHZpBRU5ZU1JUTIkFwcAOSDYMPI7rIA3B4zXmQBQZHUw3AARgjDM8gA9LvIEqLkS8G41ACMAEwAzDv7h6JAA)

```
interface XhrCaller {
    (...args: (string | unknown)[]): Promise<Record<string, unknown>>
}

const getCall : XhrCaller = (pathParam) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve({ test: 'test' });
});

getCall('abc'); // ok
getCall(123); // ok
```

Beware that you used `unknown` and it behaves like `any` so you lost all type checking when use `getCall`

```
getCall('abc'); // ok
getCall(123); // ok
```

Also, you did declare union type, but that used to check for type when you apply a value like `getCall(123)` not when you declare.

Your example basically declare another type `(pathParam: string) => Promise<unknown>` which is not compatible with `XhrCaller`

```
const getCall : XhrCaller = (pathParam: string) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve({ test: 'test' });
});
```

Comment: This is it. I was about to post the same findings 10 mins ago but you did a better job at explaining so I'm glad I didn't go forward with my effort :D

Comment: Union with `unknown` is foolishness. I actually wanted an object so I changed it to `string|Record<string, any>`